# Angular2 Can I get a count number of ngFor?

Tags: angular, ngfor

Hi I'm looping json string using ngFor but is it possible to show the number of looping items instead of showing its value?

for example in my component I have

```
items = {item1, item2, item3, item4}
```

and in html template

```
<p *ngFor="let i of items>{{i}}</p>
```

then the result will be

```
item1
item2
item3
item4
```

but instead of that, since there are four items in the object, I want to display the number 4 (a number of items in the object).

```
 4
```

How can I achieve this?

Thanks!

Comment: {{ items.length }}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will display the number on each iteration:

```
<p *ngFor="let i of items>{{ items?.length }}</p>
```

Comment: What ? does mean?

Comment: ? is called  the "safe navigation operator" and it is used to stop angular from reading undefined or null properties. If yo did not have the operator in this case and items was not defined, you would get an error.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to loop your Json String, Just use length property.

TS code:

```
 items: string[] = ['item1', 'item2', 'item3'];
```

Inside Html use it:

```
{{items.length}}
```